pacemaker + drbd failed to mount
Using:
Ubuntu 24.04LTS
pacemaker      2.1.6-5ubuntu2
corosync       3.1.7-1ubuntu3
drbd-utils     9.22.0-1build1
All ip + drbd are working, but it fails when it try to mount filesystem by pacemaker....
pcs cluster status
Cluster Status:
Cluster Summary:

Stack: corosync (Pacemaker is running)
Current DC: pauloric (version 2.1.6-6fdc9deea29) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Wed Oct 16 10:15:59 2024 on pauloric
Last change:  Wed Oct 16 09:11:20 2024 by root via cibadmin on pauloric
2 nodes configured
6 resource instances configured
Node List:
Online: [ pauloric zeus ]

PCSD Status:
pauloric: Online
zeus: Online
pcs resource

lan1        (ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2):         Started pauloric
wan1        (ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2):         Started pauloric
Clone Set: drbd_base-clone [drbd_base] (promotable):

Promoted: [ pauloric ]
Unpromoted: [ zeus ]


Resource Group: iplan:

lan       (ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2):         Started pauloric
fs_base   (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem):      Stopped (not installed)



pcs resource config drbd_base-clone
  Meta Attributes: drbd_base-clone-meta_attributes
    clone-max=2
    clone-node-max=1
    master-max=1
    master-node-max=1
    notify=true
    promotable=true
    target-role=Master
  Resource: drbd_base (class=ocf provider=linbit type=drbd)
    Attributes: drbd_base-instance_attributes
      drbd_resource=base
    Operations:
      demote: drbd_base-demote-interval-0s
        interval=0s timeout=90
      monitor: drbd_base-monitor-interval-10s
        interval=10s
      notify: drbd_base-notify-interval-0s
        interval=0s timeout=90
      promote: drbd_base-promote-interval-0s
        interval=0s timeout=90
      reload: drbd_base-reload-interval-0s
        interval=0s timeout=30
      start: drbd_base-start-interval-0s
        interval=0s timeout=240
      stop: drbd_base-stop-interval-0s
        interval=0s timeout=100

pcs resource config fs_base
  Attributes: fs_base-instance_attributes
    device=/dev/drbd0
    directory=/srv/containers/base
    fstype=ext4
  Operations:
    monitor: fs_base-monitor-interval-20s
      interval=20s timeout=80s
    start: fs_base-start-interval-0s
      interval=0s timeout=60s
    stop: fs_base-stop-interval-0s
      interval=0s timeout=60s

pcs constraint
**Colocation Set Constraints:
  Set Constraint: colocation_set_defe
    score=INFINITY
    Resource Set: colocation_set_defe_set
      Resources: 'drbd_base-clone', 'fs_base'
Order Constraints:
  start resource 'drbd_base-clone' then start resource 'fs_base' (id: order-drbd_base-clone-fs_base-
      Mandatory)
    symmetrical=1 require-all=1 kind=Mandatory**

Testing
pcs resource debug-start fs_base
Operation force-start for fs_base (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem) returned 0 (ok)
Oct 16 10:17:33 INFO: Running start for /dev/drbd0 on /srv/containers/base
pcs resource debug-start fs_base
Operation force-start for fs_base (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem) returned 0 (ok)
Oct 16 10:17:33 INFO: Running start for /dev/drbd0 on /srv/containers/base
mount | grep drbd
/dev/drbd0 on /srv/containers/base type ext4 (rw,relatime)
pcs resource debug-stop fs_base
Operation force-stop for fs_base (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem) returned 0 (ok)
Oct 16 10:19:31 INFO: Running stop for /dev/drbd0 on /srv/containers/base
Oct 16 10:19:31 INFO: Trying to unmount /srv/containers/base
Oct 16 10:19:31 INFO: No processes on /srv/containers/base were signalled. force_unmount is set to 'true'
Oct 16 10:19:32 INFO: unmounted /srv/containers/base successfully
looking at:
https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/2.1/Clusters_from_Scratch/html/
https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_reference/s1-resourcegroups-haar#s1-resourcegroups-HAAR
DRBD Failed with pacemaker
I know that should be something wrong from my part, but after reading a lot of stuff I coul not figure it out what is missing...
best regards
humm first error when I start with constrain I user set...
now I think that I write correctly:
#) pcs constraint order drbd_base-clone then fs_base kind=Mandatory symmetrical=true require-all=true

but error continues....

You need to order the FS to start after DRBD is promoted (not simply started), and colocate the FS with the promoted DRBD node.
pcs constraint colocation add fs_base with promoted drbd_base-clone
pcs constraint order promote drbd_base-clone then fs_base


Thanks Matt after reboot both server all if fine. My mystake was: pc constrain ordet set drbd_base-clone fs_base To correct this I remove this rule and insert: pcs constraint order promote drbd_base-clone then fs_base kind=Mandatory symmetrical=true require-all=true I will try too your sugestion 80)
